# Connection between limit of ratio of logarithms of functions and functions

Tags: limits

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both are positive increasing functions and both approach to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$.
We know $lim_{x \to \infty} log (f(x))/log(g(x)) =0$. Can we say
$lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/g(x) =0$?

logarithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Question:**

Try $f(x)=1-1/x^{2}$ and $g(x)=1-1/x$, this is a counterexample.

**EDIT:**

For $0<\epsilon<1$, then
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\log f(x)}{\log g(x)}<\epsilon
\end{align*}
for large $x$, it entails
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}<\dfrac{1}{g(x)}\cdot g(x)^{\epsilon}=\dfrac{1}{g(x)^{1-\epsilon}}\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
since $g(x)\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. But let us  consider the case when both f(x), g(x) tends to infinity as x tends to infinity

Comment: @Sanu, look at the new solution.